# Why is print(snapshot.hasData) returning true?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I must be misunderstanding the `hasData` method for a `QuerySnaphot`. In my `StreamBuilder` I want to return a `widget` informing the user there are no items in the `collection` queried. I've deleted the collection in Firestore so there's definitely no data there. But when I run the following code:

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance
    .collection('Events')
    .where("bandId", isEqualTo: identifier)
    .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        print('code here is being executed 1');// This gets executed
        return Text('helllllp');
      } else {
        print('Code here is being executed2'); //And this gets executed 
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Text('Loading...');
          default:
            return new ListView(
              children:
                snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  return CustomCard(
                    event: document['event'],
                    location: document['location'],
                    service: document['service'],
                    date: document['date'].toDate(),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            }
          }
        },
      ),
```

All I want to do is return a widget informing user if the snapshot is empty. For example `Text('You have no messages')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is that [`snapshots()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) will also return a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) when the query returns no documents. Thus, you could expand your condition like this:

```dart
if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) {
  return Text('You have no messages.');
} else {
  ...
}
```

Although, realistically you should not return `You have no messages` when `snapshot.data` is `null` because it is `null` before the query is completed. Hence, I would go for something like this:

```dart
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  return Text('Loading...');
} 
if (snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) {
  return Text('You have no messages.');  
}
return ListView(..);
```

This ignores error handling, however, that can also be added.
*Notice* that `snapshot.hasData` is an alternative to determining connection state using `snapshot.connectionState`.

Comment: Thank you! I searched hours to find the issue. hasData is really confusing and should get renamed